# paragraph element not found in dom node.children. and node.childNodes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement wherein a suggestion message has to be displayed near the input elements whenever it is  focused. This is what I did.

1. the input element, corresponding label and a paragraph( containing the suggestion message) are wrapped into a parent paragraph element.
2. Maintain 2 classes, one with display property as hidden and another with display property as block.
3. Add 2 listeners (focusin and focusout) for all such inputs for switching between these classes.

**The problem:**
Unable to  select the paragraph containing the suggestion message among the childNodes or the children of the parent paragraph

sample codes: html

```
<p> <label for='email'> email: </label>
                <input type='email' id='email' required pattern='^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$'placeholder='123@example.com'> </input>
                <p class='input-message-hidden'> enter your email address here. </p>
            </p>
```

javascript or js:

```
function focussed_in(event){
    targ = event.target;
    siblings = targ.parentNode.children;
    for(var i = 0 ; i< siblings.length; i++){
        alert(siblings[i]);
    }
}
```

I have added alert to understand what's happening. You get 2 alerts ... 1 for label and another for input and nothing for P tag..
thanks for helping..

Comment: You can't have a P as a child of a P, so the browser is probably making them siblings as part of error correction. Change the message element to a span. Also, there is no *display: hidden*, there's either *display: none* or *visibility: hidden*. Probably the second is better in this case.

Comment: @RobG I maintained display:none.. Its a mistake while I am writing the question.. Also why is visibility a good option here? I mean it leaves a little gap for that message. wouldn't the display idea be better

Comment: span element is being alerted.. thank u very much